# How to order by two fields ? sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

i need to run query which do the following:

1. order the table by `x` , so the result will be.
2. then it do a multiple order by for a groups according to the following x range.

so `userId_1` will be before `userId_2` , because both are in 90-100 x range.
and `userId_1 y value` **>** `userId_2 y value`.

How to implement that ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the desired effect by dropping the last digit of `x` for ordering, i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY x DIV 10, y
```